# Display images in pageblocktable column

Tags: images

I'm new in Force.com. Been trying to display my products on pageblocktable. However, the issue here is that, the product image display the same for all column. I have image field in my custom products which has a formula datatype. How do I display my image based on their product ID?

VF CODE:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Products">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!productList}" var="item" id="s">
        <apex:column value="{!item.Name}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!item.Price__c}"/> 
        <apex:column value="{!item.Size__c}"/> 
        <apex:column value="{!item.Colour__c}"/> 
        <apex:column >
            <apex:image value="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!imageURL}" id="someImage" height="200" width="300"/>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageblocktable>
</apex:pageblock>
```

CONTROLLER CODE:

```
public String imageURL{get;set;}

public list<Product__c> productList{set;get;} 

public Product ( ){
    productList= [Select Name, Price__c, Size__c, Colour__c, Image__c, ImageID__c From Product__c];

    List<document> documentList=[select id from document];
    for (document d : documentList){
        imageURL = d.id;
        productList =  [Select  Name, Price__c, Size__c, Colour__c, Image__c, ImageID__c FROM Product__c WHERE ImageID__c = :imageURL ];
    }   
}
```

thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Where's imageURL coming from and what's the value of ImageID__C on your product records ? If that's the part you need in the serverletUrl it might be as simple as ?file={!item.ImageID__c}"

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke Thanks Samuel! I created an ImageID__c field to store the image id but oversee that field. It works now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake was pointed out by Samuel. It works now by editing-> ?file={!item.ImageID__c}